# Redirecting stdout only if command failed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm writing a bash script that is supposed to be "transparent" to the user. It reads commands from the user and intercepts them, allowing only some of them to be executed by bash, depending on some criteria. It (basically) works like this:

```
while true; do
   read COMMAND
   can_be_done $COMMAND
   if [ $? == 0 ]; then
      eval $COMMAND
      if [ $? != 0 ]; then
         echo "Error: command not found"
      fi
   fi
done
```

The problem is, when the command fails, you also get stuff printed to the console. BUT, if I keep the result in a variable and only print it when it doesn't fail, like so:

```
RESULT=$(eval $COMMAND)
```

Then there's another problem: The special formatting gets lost (for example, "ls --color" doesn't show colors anymore)

My question is: Is there a way to have the command print to STDOUT if successful, but to /dev/null if it fails?

Comment: Colors aren't lost for me. RESULT=$(eval ls --color); echo "$RESULT"

Comment: @dogbane `ls --color` means `ls --color=always`. Usually `ls` is aliased to `ls --color=auto` or `ls --color=tty`, i.e. it only prints color codes when stdout is a terminal (`isatty`).

Comment: I just realized, you're right! But for some reason "ls --color=auto" does (which was the alias being used for ls). I removed the "=auto" and now colors show up with this method.

Comment: One would think that if a command fails the person needs as much information as they can get their hands on. So why mask that inforation?

Comment: @DemianDawid I wouldn't change that alias. If you use `alias ls='ls --color'` then you'll have problems using `ls` in a pipeline (when stdout is not a tty).

Comment: @JohnKugelman I realize that now... But then the question of how to solve this problem still stands :/

Comment: In my opinion, you are trying to do something very un-UNIX-like. Maybe we should step back a bit -- what's the purpose of this wrapper script? Can you achieve your goal with segregated user accounts and locked down filesystem permissions instead?

Comment: @JohnKugelman I don't like this very much either, but it's not my choice. They're making me do this for a college project... (Yeah, I know)

Comment: @DemianDawid Wow, this is a pretty bad project. It's not a good idea for a script, and it's really hard to do robustly. But hey, in the workplace you often get poorly thought out requirements as well, so in the spirit of doing what you're told, I'll take another crack at answering this...

Comment: I'll bet that your tutor didn't think of the colour issue, I can't see an easy way around that one.  You have to run the command and store the output somewhere, then only when the command is complete can you decide if it should be displayed.  Trouble is, whereever you store the output you will loose the colour.   Take a look at `script -f` in a pipeline.

Answer (score 6):

Do you really need the second part, replacing the output of the command with an error message? Linux commands print their own error messages, which aren't necessarily "command not found". You'd be hiding the true error (permission denied, file not found, out of memory, segfault, etc.) with an oftentimes incorrect error message (command not found).

If you remove that check, you could simplify the loop to something like this:

```
while true; do
   read -e COMMAND
   if can_be_done "$COMMAND"; then
      eval "$COMMAND"
   fi
done
```

- `read -e` uses readline to obtain the command, making the prompt a lot more shell-like (<kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> for history, for instance).
- `command; if [ $? == 0 ]; then` is more idiomatically written as `if <command>; then`.
- Quoting makes sure special characters and whitespace are handled properly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. As you can probably tell, I'm pretty new to bash scripting!

Answer (score 1):

I would argue strongly that you should *not* do this.  If you do not want to see output, redirect it to `/dev/null`.  If you do want to see errors, do not redirect stderr.  If you are using a program that prints its error messages on stdout instead of stderr, FIX THE PROGRAM!  Error messages belong on stderr.  Note that this means your program is broken, as it ought to read:

```
 echo "Error: command not found" >&2
```

I'm not sure if it is rule number 1, but it certainly belongs in the top 10, and it may be the most often violated rule:  `Error messages belong on stderr`.  A program which prints error messages on stdout is broken.

Answer (score 0):

`if false > /dev/null;then echo 1; else echo 2; fi 2> /dev/null`

Will output `2`

`if true > /dev/null;then echo 1; else echo 2; fi 2> /dev/null`

Will output `1`

remove the `> /dev/null` to print the command also to stdout

for example
`if echo 123;then echo 1; else echo 2; fi 2> /dev/null`

Will output
`123` & `1`

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the command is not very expensive to run you can do this:

```
   test `ls /mooo 2>/dev/null` || echo moo not found
```

test will return true only if the command exits with 0, in this case ls is the command. You could have put this in an if statement too like so:

```
if [ `ls /moo 2>/dev/null` ];then 
  echo moo is a folder
fi
```

Comment: `if ls; then` checks ls's exit code. ``if [ `ls` ]`` is equivalent to ``if [ -n `ls` ]``; it checks that ls didn't output anything.